# can't resolve error \x93 when call my print function

Tags: python, char

I'm reposting the question because unsolved or inefficiently answered, filled with some missing info.
After several iteration in loop of my print function without problem, I face to this error I can't figure out: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x93' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>`, but. you'll see better on traceback down below.

j is a string ( a flag I use for my ref. into the file.. You can take any..); `h` take value of gh when passed the function `prt_tit_gen`. `dir_conf+ct` are strings respectively a dir and a name file where to print in..
For what I can understand (because appear on spyder debuger ), the text code is `utf-8`.

The routine is (`gh` is the "exploded" format for debugging purpose) :

```
   gh = j+' -> '+str(' '.join(e))+"\n"
   prt_tit_gen(dir_conf+ct , gh , 'a')
```

where

```
def prt_tit_gen(d,h,m):
    file1 = open(d, m)
    file1.writelines(h)
    file1.close()
```

and

```
e = [
'zip:GY1 1WW',
'sector:Financial Services',
'longBusinessSummary:Eurocastle Investment Limited is a publicly traded closed-ended investment company that focuses on investing in performing and nonperforming loans and other real estate related assets primarily in Italy. The Company is Euro denominated and is listed on Euronext Amsterdam under the symbol Â“ECTÂ”. Eurocastle is managed by an affiliate of Fortress Investment Group LLC, a leading global investment manager. For more information regarding Eurocastle Investment Limited and to be added to our email distribution list, please visit www.eurocastleinv.com.',
'city:Saint Peter Port',
'country:Guernsey',
'regularMarketPrice:8.3',
'preMarketPrice:None',
'logo_url:https://logo.clearbit.com/eurocastleinv.com'
]
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "D:\Documenti\Develope\Python\AI\Previsone Titoli\getTiker Sector.py", line 89, in <module>
    prt_tit_gen(dir_conf+ct, j+' -> '+str(' '.join(e))+"\n", 'a')
  File "D:\Documenti\Develope\Python\AI\Previsone Titoli\getTiker Sector.py", line 45, in prt_tit_gen
    file1.writelines(h)
  File "C:\Program Files\Linguaggi\Python397\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x93' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file with a specified encoding like this

```
file1 = open(d, m, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: refined Traceback due to lack of size post.. :
    File "D:\Documenti\Develope\Python\AI\Previsone Titoli\getTiker Sector.py", line 36, in readFileOut
    data = my_file.read()
  File "C:\Program Files\Linguaggi\Python397\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 1468: invalid start byte

Comment: Sorry raizo, I wrong the open to place your amendment.. now seams its works... need to check better. For now, thanks !!